# How to set variable inline in gitlab-ci.yaml based on regex matching?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a variable in gitlab-ci.yaml based on the name of the branch.

Suppose I am pushing to a branch named `3.2.7`

Here is the situation:

```
include:
  - template: "Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml"

variables:
  PRODUCTION_BRANCH: "master"
  STAGING_BRANCH: (\d)\.(\d)\.(\d)

.deploy_rules:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /$STAGING_BRANCH/'
      variables:
        SERVER_PORT: 3007  # TODO: should be 300d ; d is the second digit
```

I want to generate `3002` inline using regex matching.

How can I do this?

I have done some research and seems I have to use `sed` but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it and how to do it.

**TO MAKE THE PROBLEM SIMPLER**

```
include:
  - template: "Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml"

variables:
  TEST_VAR: sed -E 's/(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d)/300\2/gm;t;d' <<< $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

stages:
  - temp

temp:
  stage: temp
  script:
    - echo $TEST_VAR
```

Should be echoing `3002` but it is echoing `sed -E 's/(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d)/300\2/gm;t;d' <<< 3.2.7`

Comment: Any reason you can't just write the regex pattern directly into the rule?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use variables in the regex pattern. You just have to write the regex  verbatim, it cannot be directly parameterized. You also cannot use `sed` or other Linux utilities in `variables:` or other parts of your yaml. You're bound to the limitations of YAML specification and features provided by GitLab.

However, there is an option available to you that will fit your stated use case.

### Dynamic variables

> TEST_VAR: sed -E 's/(\d).(\d).(\d)/300\2/gm;t;d' <<< $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

While you can't use `sed` or other utilities directly in `variables:` declarations, you can use [dotenv artifacts via `artifacts:reports:dotenv`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) to set variables dynamically.

For example, a job can use `sed` or whatever other utilities you like to create variables which will be used by the rest of the pipeline.

```yaml
stages:
  - temp

create_variables:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - TEST_VAR="$(sed -E 's/(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d)/300\2/gm;t;d' <<< ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH})"
    - echo "TEST_VAR=${TEST_VAR}" >> dotenv.txt
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: dotenv.txt

temp:
  stage: temp
  script:
    - echo $TEST_VAR
```

Here, the `.pre` stage is used, which is a special stage that is *always* ordered before every other stage. The dotenv artifact from the `create_variables` job will dynamically create variables for the jobs in subsequent stages that receive the artifact.

Comment: And I can set the variable during the stage instead of creating a pre stage

Comment: Hi @AminBa In general, it's best to ask just 1 question at a time. I would suggest you open a new question on how to use perl to achieve your goal. And unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Perl to provide a solution for this case. However, if this answer answers your initial question about setting the GitLab CI variables, please consider voting and accepting.

Comment: I think it is better if I do it like this:
`
str="3.1.2"
if [[ $str =~ 'master' ]]; then
  echo "3000"
elif [[ 'str =~ /(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d)/' ]]; then
  echo "match: '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'"
else
  echo "no match found!"
fi
` Howerver `BASH_REMATCH[1]` does not work. Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354373/how-to-use-regex-in-bash-and-capture-a-group